# How to hide SharePoint 2013 managed metadata column in document information panel

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-2013, customcolumn

In my SharePoint 2013 solution I have created a custom managed metadata field definition. The field has the attribute ShowInFileDlg set to False, so I expect the column does not show up in the document information panel. When opening a new Word document the column does show in de document information panel. Other field types (text, choice) with the ShowInFileDlg set to False are not showing.

I found some people saying this is a SharePoint bug, but cannot find a good confirmation. Does anybody know if this is in fact a SharePoint bug? Or does anyone have a good workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received an answer from Microsoft on this issue and they confirm setting the ShowInFileDlg attribute to false isn't working for managed metadata columns. This problem isn't going to be fixed in the foreseeable future, but they offered a couple of workarounds:

- Creating a custom Infopath Document Information Panel form for your
  content type let's you delete the managed metadata fields.
- Setting the columns to readonly let's them hide from the DIP.

Unfortunately the workarounds didn't provide a good solution for my problem, but maybe it's helpful for someone else.